# Compiler Problem

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler

I have no clue anymore and I have to ask some clever people now, since I just recently started working with Ubuntu.

Soo here is the Problem:

- I got Ubuntu 16.04 on a Virtual computer via VirtualBox (I don't know if this matters)
- I am trying to install an tile server for a university project and i followed this instruction 
  https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/tile-server-ubuntu/

  - In this instruction I followed every step and everything seemed fine (I did everything except the "Alternatively, install ...." )

After the installations it asks you to Verify that Mapnik has been installed correctly, and that is where I am struggling right now:

It tells me that i cannot import my name MemoryDatasource - I already figured that I have a Problem with my compiler ( I hope I figured right ) but when I am checking for the g++ compiler it tells me it is available, but I can not set the compiler with the

command `g++ -std=c++14` 
to the compiler I need and tells me

```
g++: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated
```

[Example of the Problem I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpWSp.png)

I am really grateful for any Hint/Tip there, I tried many things with the g++ but it always gave me this error. Thank you all already.

Greetings

Comment: You are not providing input file to be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

This does not look like an error:  If you type `man g++` you will see that the form of the command `g++` requires an input file to compile.  What you are doing instead, is starting the command with an option, but not specifying what the compiler is to do.

For example, if you enter only `g++` you will also receive a 'No input file' error.

If you wish to compile a program with the switch, for form of the command would be

`g++ -std=c++14 <filename>` where  is the name of the file in your directory that you wish to compile.

I'm not a python person, but FWIW it seems that you have a problem with your python bindings perhaps - your installation instructions have a set for adding the python bindings immediately above the section about verifying that mapnik has been installed.